# Problem with running crawl command due to path

Tags: python-3.x, path, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm following a tutorial online about running a simple crawler from the command prompt. When I get to running the crawler, I get (what I believe is) a bunch of path related errors. My path is well established, when I open my command prompt and write 'Python', everything comes out okay.

**Here is my Python code for the crawler, using Scrapy:**

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'quotes'
    allowed_domains = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['quotes.toscrape.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        h1_tag = response.xpath('//h1/a/text()').extract_first()
        tags = response.xpath('//*[@class="tag-item"]/a/text()').extract()

        yield {'H1 tag': h1_tag, 'Tags': tags}
```

When I run it in PyCharm, it runs without any errors and ends with code 0.

*This is the line I use in my command prompt to crawl C:\Users\Kev\Desktop\quotes_spider>scrapy crawl quotes....*

**Here are the errors I'm getting from the command propmt:**

```
2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 
0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console 
listening on 127.0.0.1:6023 
2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining 
start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 127, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 83, in start_requests
     yield Request(url, dont_filter=True)
   File "c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
   File "c:\users\kev\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 62, in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
 ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: quotes.toscrape.com
 2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 12, 34, 10, 194671),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 21, 12, 34, 10, 185685)}
 2019-06-21 08:34:10 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I'm basically expecting to get a "Crawled (200) < GET" line which would indicate that the code/crawling ran successfully.

I'm assuming this is somehow related to the path because of the error message but I don't understand how that's possible since my path is well established.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `start_urls` from:

```
start_urls = ['quotes.toscrape.com']
```

to:

```
start_urls = ['http://www.quotes.toscrape.com']
```

It should start with `http(s)://`. Only `allowed_domains` shouldn't have `http(s)://`.

Comment: Thank you so much, now it's working perfectly! I'll keep that in mind for the future. Have a good day!